# Resizing an exFAT partion

Tags: partitioning, exfat

I have an exFAT partition on my external hard drive which I'd like to grow. GParted doesn't support resizing exFAT partitions, but is there another way to do it? I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score -2):

Since it's an external hard drive I'd recommend using a Windows computer.

exFAT is a Microsoft format and you'll get less headaches if you resize it on a Microsoft environment.

Comment: I tried to use diskmgmt.msc and both the "Expand Volume" and "Shrink Volume" options were greyed out. Since exFAT is based on FAT, could that mean it isn't possible to resize?

Comment: The question asks how to do it.  This answer talks about where to do it, apparently assuming it's straightforward if done in Windows.  It doesn't really answer the question.